# Determining if two lines intersect in 3D

Tags: calculus, parametric

If I have for example two lines in $3d$, presented in parametric form,

$L1: x= 3t+2, ~y=t+6, ~z=2t-9$

$L2: x= t+5, ~y=3t+7, ~z=t+3$

and I want to find if they intersect, do I set the t variable for $L2$ to s and solve simultaneously or is there a different approach?

Answer (score 4):

Write the system of three equations in two unknowns

$$\begin{cases}
3t+2=\ \ t'+5\\
\ \ t+6=3t'+7\\
2t-9=\ \ t'+3\\
\end{cases}$$

Either solve two $2\times2$ systems and compare the solutions, or put it in a standard form and check that the determinant is zero (i.e. rank $2$).

---

In this particular case, a quick solution is obtained by subtracting the first equation from the second(three times) and from the third.

$$\begin{cases}
-8t=-8\\
-t-11=-2
\end{cases}$$

This doesn't seem very compatible...

Comment: The key observation here is that in the parametrization, the $t$ for $L1$ is not 'the same as' the $t$ for $L2$.

Comment: clearly a better way. thanks for sharing!

Comment: @MaxPayne: though in the end it leads to just the same computation, of course :)

Comment: Is there no quick matrix method like by using Jacobians?

Comment: @Narasimham: hem, can you find quicker than a single $3\times3$ determinant computation for a problem with $8$ DOFs ? A jacobian would lose affine information and is certainly not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the lines are **not parallel**. Now finding the shortest distance between the two lines. If they intersect, shortest distance will be zero.

You may find the shortest distance using by finding the projection of a vector joining the two lines along the **common normal**. The S given below is **not** the shortest distance, but it will be zero if the lines intersect.

$$S = [<3,1,12> <3,1,2> <1,3,1>]$$

**Note:** $[\rm a\ b\ c]$ represents the scalar triple product.

Comment: "You may find the shortest distance using by finding the projection of a vector joining the two lines along the common normal", could you clarify this ?